# Hacking into $stateProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need a way to hack into `$stateProvider`. This is why:

```
angular.module('rects', []).config(($stateProvider)=> {
    $stateProvider.state({
        name: 'rectangles',
        templateUrl: 'list.html',
        controller: 'listController',
        data: {
            foo: 'rectangles foo'
        }
    })
})

angular.module('circles', []).config(($stateProvider)=> {
     $stateProvider.state({
         name: 'circles',
         templateUrl: 'list.html',
         controller: 'listController',
         data: {
            foo: 'circles foo'
         }
     })
})
```

Now `foo` appears in controller in `$state.current.data` and this is fine. But now I need to tweak `data` for rectangles, I have to use another service or factory to process data, I cannot inject another service in `config` section, I cannot use `resolve` to throw extra thing into the controller because then I'm gonna have dependency problem or I will have to use `resolve` with that extra thing in every single state used in `listController`. But maybe I could do something like this:

```
angular.module('rects', []).config(($stateProvider)=> {
    $stateProvider.state({
        ...
        ...
        resolve: {
            $state: function(myFookingService) {
                this.data.foo = myFookingService.fookDatTing('rectangles foo');
                return this;
            }
        }
    })
})
```

But of course this doesn't work. I do still think it's possible, but I can't get the syntax right.

**upd**: kinda found a way:

```
angular.module('rects', []).config(($stateProvider)=> {
    $stateProvider.state({
        name: 'rectangles'
        ...
        ...
        controllerProvider:($state, myFookingService)=> {
            $state.get('rectangles').data.foo = myFookingService.fookDatTing('rectangles foo');
            return 'listController'
        }
    })
})
```

question: how dangerous is this approach? Could that come and bite me in the ass later?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? before we go down the XY route

Comment: I need to change `$state.current.data.foo` for `rects`, it needs to be calculated using another service, in my case via `myFookingService`